# VS Code Oracle Developer Hide SQL in Results Window

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code Extension.  When I run a SQL statement a Results Tab opens displaying the SQL statement and records retrieved.

How can I hide the SQL statement in the Results tab?  I don't want to see it with my data rows.

This is the Extension:

[image]

This is the SQL Tab:

[image]

This is the SQL Results Tab:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be controlled using the `oracledevtools.query.echo` setting, but note you'll need to reload any windows before the setting will take effect:

[image: oracledevtools.query.echo setting]

You may also wiuth to bump the `oracledevtools.query.resultSet.pageSize` setting to 25 at the same time:

[image: oracledevtools.query.resultSet.pageSize setting]